# Actual difference in implementing/overriding using @abstractproperty and @abstractmethod

Tags: python, properties, abstract, abc

Consider an abstract base class with a function which you want each subsequent subclass to override. Using the abc module and ABCMeta; does decorating with `@abstractproperty` or `@abstractmethod` actually force the subclass/developer implementing to create the type of function specified by the decorator? From my experiments you can override an abstract property with a method and an abstract method with a property in the subclass.

Is this notion incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notion is correct; the `ABCMeta` code does not distinguish between a `abstractproperty` and a `abstractmethod`.

Both of these decorators add an attribute to the decorated item, `.__isabstractmethod__`, which `ABCMeta` uses to add an `.__abstractmethods__` attribute (a `frozenset`) to the ABC you defined. The `object` type then guards against creating an instance of any class where any of the names listed in `.__abstractmethods__` does not have a concrete implementation. No checks are made for functions versus properties there.

To illustrate:

```
>>> from abc import *
>>> class C:
...     __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
...     @abstractmethod
...     def abstract_method(self): pass
...     @abstractproperty
...     def abstract_property(self): return 'foo'
... 
>>> C.__abstractmethods__
frozenset(['abstract_method', 'abstract_property'])
```

By creating new overrides for these in a subclass, the `ABCMeta` class will find fewer methods or properties with the `. __isabstractmethod__` attribute, thus making the resulting `__abstractmethods__` set smaller; once the set is empty you can create instances of such a subclass.

These checks are made in the [`ABCMeta.__new__` constructor](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/abc.py#l86) and no checks are made to match descriptor types:

```
cls = super(ABCMeta, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
# Compute set of abstract method names
abstracts = set(name
             for name, value in namespace.items()
             if getattr(value, "__isabstractmethod__", False))
for base in bases:
    for name in getattr(base, "__abstractmethods__", set()):
        value = getattr(cls, name, None)
        if getattr(value, "__isabstractmethod__", False):
            abstracts.add(name)
cls.__abstractmethods__ = frozenset(abstracts)
```

You'd have to create a subclass of `ABCMeta` that overrides the `__new__` method, and check that any abstract method or property named on a base class is indeed matched with a non-abstract method or property on `cls` instead.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, confirmed my suspicions. I don't think that I should have to do override `__new__`, rather it should already work like that. I guess the developers have overlooked this or do you think that there is some reason for them not to actually check the function type?

Comment: @Parham: I think it's a simplification; no tests are made for the function signature either, for example. The goal is not to force a specific interface, the goal is to make ducktyping easier. The developer is still responsible for providing a working implementation.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Was pretty much was I assumed. Thank you!