# abc.abstractmethod + property

Tags: python, properties, abc

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#abc) it should work to combine `@property` and `@abc.abstractmethod` so the following should work in python3.3:

```
import abc

class FooBase(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def greet(self):
        """ must be implemented in order to instantiate """
        pass

    @property
    def greet_comparison(self):
        """ must be implemented in order to instantiate """
        return 'hello'

class Foo(FooBase):
    def greet(self):
        return 'hello'
```

test the implementation:

```
In [6]: foo = Foo()
In [7]: foo.greet
Out[7]: <bound method Foo.greet of <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f935a971f10>>

In [8]: foo.greet()
Out[8]: 'hello'
```

so it is obviously not a property, because then it should work like that:

```
In [9]: foo.greet_comparison
Out[9]: 'hello'
```

Maybe I'm to stupid or it simply doesn't work, somebody has an idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want `greet` to be a property, you still need to use the `@property` decorator in your implementation:

```
class Foo(FooBase):
    @property
    def greet(self):
        return 'hello'
```

All that an ABC metaclass does is test wether or not you have provided the same name in the concrete class; it doesn't care if it is a method or a property or a regular attribute.

Because it doesn't care, it doesn't magically apply `property` decorators either. This is a *good* thing; perhaps in a specific implementation a static attribute is enough to satisfy the requirement, and a property would be overkill.

The purpose of a ABC metaclass is to help you detect gaps in your implementation; it never was intended to enforce the types of the attributes.

Note that before Python 3.3 you can not combine a `@property` with an `@abstractmethod`. You would have to use an [`@abstractproperty` decorator](http://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty) instead. There is an ambiguity there when your property needs more than a simple getter in that case; Python 3.3 covers that case much better (see [issue 11610](http://bugs.python.org/issue11610) for the painful details).

Comment: If you were to have an abstract setter, would decorating greet fulfill the override requirement? Just a point of interest.

Comment: @m.brindley: if `greet in dir(Foo)` works, it satisfies as an override. See this [previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441619/actual-difference-in-implementing-overriding-using-abstractproperty-and-abstra/14441682#14441682) on how ABC checks for overrides.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, one small thing on your last sentence, i i used it because the [python3.3 docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#improved-modules) mention, that the `@abstractproperty` decorator is deprecticated.

Comment: Ah, I had not seen that yet; thanks for pointing that out! It does make sense; by supporting property methods like that an ambiguity (that I was not aware of) is resolved very nicely!

Comment: newer versions of python deprecate the `abstractproperty` decorator again. now one just needs to use `property` and `abstractmethod` together, and the order seems to matter